# Writing a path to a property file using ant

Tags: ant, batch-file, dos

I am writing a file path to a property file using ant property file task,below is my code snippet of ant

```
<propertyfile  file="WeblogicDomain.properties" comment="Weblogic Properties Below">
    <entry  key="path" value="C:/bea"/>
</propertyfile>
```

In the output properties i.e.., WeblogicDomain.properties file the path varies as shown below

```
path=C\:/bea
```

i was puzzled with this, is there a solution to resolve this & place the exact path as mentioned in source code

My ant version : 1.6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `java.util.Properties` works.  The colon `:` and equals `=` characters are used as name value delimiters so colons are escaped when part of the key or value and not the delimiter.

See [`java.util.Properties.load(Reader)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) for more.